# BeautifulSoup get everything in a JSON list at specific element

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

Day 2 of BS and JSON, just for a specific use case.

using requests and beautifulsoup4

found_json contains all the information I want, but I want a section of it.

```
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = bs(page.text, "html.parser")
found = soup.find("script", {"id": "__NEXT_DATA__"})
found_json = found.text   # json lives here
```

data example:

```
{"first_layer":{"second_layer":{"third_layer":{"id":"KYOU","liveData":{"....
```

I'm trying to get everything in that third layer and save it off somewhere. Is there any way to access that using BS, or should I look at the JSON library?

Comment: Why not just turn it to a python `dict` so you can easily parse the dict in python?...better practice is probably to use `import json` and `json.loads(json)`, but `eval(json)` is a different option that I use occasionally, but I don't gather the eval to accomplish from the web normally

Comment: @ViaTech It may work, but I'd never run `eval` on data that comes from the Internet for security reasons.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg yes 100%, this is why I updated the comment to use `json.loads`

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at the json library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use `json`

```
import json
... your code ...
found_json = json.loads(found.text)
data = found_json.get('first_layer').get('second_layer').get('third_layer')
```